# Unnesting/rectangling/flattening a nested list using `tidyr::unnest_longer()`

Tags: r, tidyr, nested-lists

I've been trying to get my head around the unnesting functions in `tidyr` and `tibblify`. I believe you should be able to use `unnest_longer()`  to replicate the more manual methods below of turning this kind of nested list into a tibble, but I've been struggling with the docs a little. A correct example of how to do this would help me immensely:

```r
# Example nested list
nl <- list(time = list("2023-02-06", "2023-02-07", "2023-02-08",
                       "2023-02-09", "2023-02-10", "2023-02-11",
                       "2023-02-12"), 
           precipitation_sum = list(0.9, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0))

# one way to do it (extract colnames and construct)
tibble(!!! setNames(map(nl, unlist),names(nl)))

# another way (collect & reduce each sublist)
as_tibble(lapply(nl, function(x) Reduce(c, x)))

# how to use tidyr and unnest_longer? (below is incorrect)
unnest_longer(tibble(nl), col = everything())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
as_tibble(nl) %>% 
    unnest(cols = where(is.list))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  time       precipitation_sum
  <chr>                  <dbl>
1 2023-02-06               0.9
2 2023-02-07               0  
3 2023-02-08               0  
4 2023-02-09               0.3
5 2023-02-10               0  
6 2023-02-11               0  
7 2023-02-12               0
```

---

Or more compactly

```
library(purrr)
map_dfc(nl, unlist)
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  time       precipitation_sum
  <chr>                  <dbl>
1 2023-02-06               0.9
2 2023-02-07               0  
3 2023-02-08               0  
4 2023-02-09               0.3
5 2023-02-10               0  
6 2023-02-11               0  
7 2023-02-12               0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another intersting option is to use `dmap` (and the history behind `dmap`):

'`purrrlyr` contains some functions that lie at the intersection of `purrr` and `dplyr`. They have been removed from `purrr` in order to make the package lighter and because they have been replaced by other solutions in the `tidyverse`.' https://github.com/hadley/purrrlyr/

```
#install.packages("purrrlyr")
library(purrrlyr)
nl %>% 
  dmap(unlist)
```

```
  time       precipitation_sum
  <chr>                  <dbl>
1 2023-02-06               0.9
2 2023-02-07               0  
3 2023-02-08               0  
4 2023-02-09               0.3
5 2023-02-10               0  
6 2023-02-11               0  
7 2023-02-12               0
```